# Layout differs on same set of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I am working on a UI which targets all screens across all the android versions.
 Now, I am testing on the two device, sony experia Neo v having specification :
 **480 x 854 pixels, 3.7 inches (~265 ppi pixel density) Android OS- 2.3.4**,
 and the other device  HTC Desire X Dual SIM having specification:
 **480 x 800 pixels, 4.0 inches (~233 ppi pixel density) Android Os- 4.1.1**.

The problem here is that both the device, as per my understanding, is of normal screen and hdpi,
 they both are **picking from the same layout folder** too, but the UI differs drastically on both this device. 
 HTC is rendering as expected but UI on Sony Experia is a disaster.
 The major issue I am facing is that UI look and feel in eclipse preview screens is same as HTC but Sony experia  doesn't seems to render it well.

Other point, which I have noticed is when I am running the emulator with configuration:
 3.7 FWVGA 480*854:hdpi android-2.3.4, which is exactly same as Sony Experia config, is also rendering exactly like  sony experia,
 but as soon as I edit the emuator to andrdoid 4.1.1 3.7 FWVGA 480*854:hdpi it starts displaying as expected.
 So, I am here bit confused, do Ui displays depends on Android Os version too?

Following is my **layout code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/availbtn"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:layout_height="33dip"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_button_selected"
                android:text="Available"

                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_avail_coupon_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_circle_selected"
                android:text="07"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/usedbtn"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:layout_height="33dip"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_button_nselected"
                android:text="Used"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_used_coupon_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_circle_nselected"
                android:text="10"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/expirebtn"
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:layout_height="33dip"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_button_nselected"
                android:text="Expired"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_expired_coupon_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_circle_nselected"
                android:text="01"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </FrameLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_button"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/coupons_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the UI screen shot for 3.7 FWVGA 480*854:hdpi on android-2.3.4 and  3.7 FWVGA 480*854:hdpi on android 4.1.1 respectively:[image: android-2.3.4]

[image: android 4.1.1]

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/availbtn"
                    android:layout_width="102dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_button_selected"
                    android:text="Available"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_avail_coupon_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle_selected"
                    android:text="07"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/usedbtn"
                    android:layout_width="102dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_button_nselected"
                    android:text="Used"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_used_coupon_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle_nselected"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/expirebtn"
                    android:layout_width="102dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_button_nselected"
                    android:text="Expired"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_expired_coupon_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle_nselected"
                    android:text="01"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/coupons_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I didn't understand your logic why did you replace my FrameLayout with LinearLayout,this is utter ridiculous. How this will give same result, did you ever try this code? .. Your answer deserve to be down-vote.

Comment: I used FrameLayout for some purpose, to get the desired UI. Please try to read question before answering them